# joomla-restrict articles access from multiple users to their own articles

Tags: joomla, acl, joomla-extensions

I have multiple articles relating to different system guides; there are loads of clients on the Joomla system that will need to view them, but I want each user to see only what they should and not all of it, some of them will have articles specifically relating to one then the other.
Is there a Joomla feature or extension to help out, please?

Comment: Please check this useful tutorial: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this extension : http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/acl-manager

But, better would be if you set permission based on user-groups, rather than users.